# Are GEMs parallel plate capacitors?

Tags: particle-physics

I am studying different forms of GEMs (Gas Electron Multiplier) and some literature uses the word *parallel plate capacitor* (Mansfield, Understanding Physics p. 457). 
However, I am not sure if this apply to all GEMs of having many plates.

I claim about one GEM foil that it is a parallel plate capacitor (standard one). 
I am however not sure if it is enough. 
There is of course little deviation of diameters in the foils, causing unavoidable effect. 
I would like to get a holistic approach on GEMs.

This is just a theoretical topic. 
Is there any sense of having non-parallel GEM foils in the GEM system?

Comment: Can you give a bit more context - an example of a GEM that you believe is _not_ a parallel plate capacitor; why you are asking the question (what about a "non parallel plate" capacitor?), etc? The electrodes will always have some effective capacitance by virtue of the electric field between them; and since you care about a uniform electric field, it makes sense to keep the plates parallel. But "every" GEM?

Comment: @Floris This is just a theoretical topic. I claim that one GEM is parallel plate capacitor. I just want to make sure that it is enough.

Comment: As I said - if you care about uniform multiplication properties you need a uniform electric field and the plates would have to be parallel.